# jqGrid: Sorting local data clears grid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I've found similar but not identical questions on here; none of their posted answers solve this.

I have local data loaded using `addJSONData`. When you click a column header to sort, the grid is wiped. There are no errors in the web console/firebug. Data added by later calls to `addJSONData` is sorted by the selected column, at least.

My config:

```
jQuery('#attributes').jqGrid({
    sortable:true,
    datatype:"local",
    colNames: cols,
    colModel: colmods,
    cmTemplate: {width:155, align:"left"},
    multiselct: false,
    shrinkToFit:false,
    caption: "Node Attributes",
    scroll: true,
    footerrow: true,
    userDataOnFooter: true,
    rowNum: -1
});
```

My only idea is to save the data `onSortCol` and reload it in `loadComplete`. I don't much like that though. I've tried various combinations of `rowNum: 9007199254740992`, `loadonce: true` and others.

I've tried jqGrid versions 4.2.0 and 4.4.0 (in which `rowNum: -1` is supported again).

*Edit*: The line that clears the data is the `emptyRows` bit in the sortData function:

```
        if(ts.p.scroll) {
            var sscroll = ts.grid.bDiv.scrollLeft;
            emptyRows.call(ts, true, false);
            ts.grid.hDiv.scrollLeft = sscroll;
        }
```

Seems like the data should be saved before this happens, but I'm not familiar with this code to know where the data actually lives.

Answer (score 0):

I'm newcomer to jqGRid (I only started to use it 3 days ago...) but, if you are using local, don't you also have to specify loadonce:true for sorting and paging to work?

Comment: Maybe, but setting that alone doesn't fix the problem unfortunately. Data is still wiped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I stumbled onto a fix though. After setting loadonce: true, if you hit the refresh button in the pager and then try to sort, it works fine.

So I force a click on the refresh button by doing something like: `$(".ui-icon-refresh").trigger('click');`

I ran this on the onClose event because that suited my requirements. You can check out my entire explanation on this issue here: [Make 'Search' remote and everything else (sorting, pagination, etc) local in jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936149/make-search-remote-and-everything-else-sorting-pagination-etc-local-in-jqg)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Something else must be going on here though. I tried triggering the refresh as you suggested, but that itself caused the grid to wipe. Triggering it before or after sorting didn't solve the issue. (I'm not really sure why this would work either -- with `loadonce:true` set, the `trigger(reloadGrid)` that's called from the click event in question doesn't execute.)

Comment: Oh, are you doing it like on the onClose event like so:
         
onClose: function(){
$("#list2").trigger("reloadGrid");
$("#list2").setGridParam({loadonce: true});
$(".ui-icon-refresh").trigger('click');
}