# jqgrid client sorting server paging gotcha.....using the latest version

Tags: jqgrid

Client side sorting works fine when I set loadonce to true. I tried doing that during the  onSortCol event but the pager is getting disabled. Setting 'datatype' to 'local' isnt enabling client side sorting. The datatype is initially 'json', and the url points to an asmx webmethod. I planned on using the onPaging method as described in numerous stack overflow posts to change the datatype to json to again enable server side paging.

i.e. Setting 'datatype' to 'local' isnt enabling client side sorting, but setting 'loadonce' to true is.

Is there a way out of this, as in can I enable the pager and restore the values after loadcomplete or gridcomplete by checking if loadonce has been set to true. If so, how do I do that?

The file I am working on is huge hence, I do not want to post the contents. I am pretty sure it does not have any mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to achieve is server-side searching and client-side sorting/paging try this: [Make 'Search' remote and everything else (sorting, pagination, etc) local in jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936149/make-search-remote-and-everything-else-sorting-pagination-etc-local-in-jqg)